# How to Create Calculate column using other Lists

Tags: sharepoint-online, calculated-column, calculated-column-formula, sharepoint-list

I have a DB on my SharePoint site using several Lists. For one of the lists I need to count Total, Pending and Completed records from the other tables.

There's one list for each department and on it each user has a number of procedures they must read if the procedure has been completed then it's set to Completed otherwise will show Pending. So I need three calculated values in my Users list, Total will count the number of items for the user and will select the table according to the department. Pending will count only the items set to Pending and Same for completed.

My lists are like this:

```
HR (Procedure Name, Status, Name, Email)
IT (Procedure Name, Status, Name, Email)
Marketing (Procedure Name, Status, Name, Email)
.
.
.
Users table has the following columns
Name, Email, Department, Total, Pending, Completed
```

So if the user belongs to the HR department then the Total, Pending and Completed columns will be fetch from that list.
Is there a way to achieve this using the Calculated Value column?

Comment: No, in calculated column, you can't retrieve values from columns in other lists. Any specific reason that you're storing data into separate departments. You could add a column called [Department] and store all items in one list and then use [Group By] to count Total, Pending, and completed.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, ***it's impossible to use other list's field in calculated column***. As a workaround, I would suggest you create a **MS Flow** to achieve this.

Use the if condition in the MS Flow to refer to other list, then update field in current list.

Answer (score 1):

No, It's not supported, please check **[The list of supported and unsupported columns in SharePoint calculated column](https://spgeeks.devoworx.com/supported-fields-in-calculated-column-sharepoint/)**

---

**Workarounds**

- Create a lookup column from another ist in your current list then create a workflow to use this value and update your list item.

> Check the detailed steps at [How to use Lookup field in SharePoint Calculated Column Formula.](https://spgeeks.devoworx.com/lookup-field-in-calculated-column-sharepoint/)

- Use Microsoft Automate as mentioned at [Update a secondary SharePoint list using Flow](https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Power-Automate-Community-Blog/Update-a-secondary-SharePoint-list-using-Flow/ba-p/38201)